# Using TensorFlow Keras to Train a DNN. Why Does Accuracy Cap-Off When Using Dropout

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression, dropout

I'm using TensorFlow Keras to build and fit a Deep Neural Network (DNN).
I've been encouraged to use Dropout layers by the literature I have read. But when I add `dropout` layers with value of `0.5`, my gradient decent progression acts weird. Specifically, the Training Accuracy and the Validation Accuracy seem to be capped off at some hard limit.

What is this effect?  Why is it happening?
Any comments or feedback would be appreciated.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 136)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 84)                11508     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 84)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 84)                336       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 42)                3570      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 42)                168       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 42)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 21)                903       
=================================================================
Total params: 16,485
Trainable params: 16,233
Non-trainable params: 252
```

[image: matplotlib.pyplot Accuracy]

Here is some of the code:

```
InputCount = 136
OutputCount = 21
H1_Count = 84
H2_Count = 42
H3_Count = 0
H4_Count = 0
initializer = 'he_normal'
activation = ['' ,'elu','elu','elu','elu']
dropout    = [0.5,0.5  ,0.5  ,0.5  ,0.5  ]
batch_norm = 1

optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
loss = 'mse' 

epochs = 500
batch_size = 10000  #Stochatic mini-batch size

model = Sequential()

if (dropout[0] > 0) :
    model.add(Dropout(dropout[0], input_shape=(InputCount,)) )
    model.add(Dense(H1_Count, activation=activation[1], kernel_initializer=initializer ))
    if (dropout[1] > 0) : model.add(Dropout(dropout[1]))
else :
    model.add(Dense(H1_Count, activation=activation[1], kernel_initializer=initializer, input_shape=(InputCount,) ))
    if (dropout[1] > 0) : model.add(Dropout(dropout[1]))

if (batch_norm == 1) : model.add(BatchNormalization())

if (H2_Count > 0) :
    model.add(Dense(H2_Count,activation=activation[2], kernel_initializer=initializer))
    if (batch_norm == 1) : model.add(BatchNormalization())
    if (dropout[2] > 0) : model.add(Dropout(dropout[2]))

if (H3_Count > 0) :
    model.add(Dense(H3_Count, activation=activation[3], kernel_initializer=initializer))
    if (batch_norm == 1) : model.add(BatchNormalization())
    if (dropout[3] > 0) : model.add(Dropout(dropout[3]))

if (H4_Count > 0) :
    model.add(Dense(H4_Count, activation=activation[4], kernel_initializer=initializer))
    if (batch_norm == 1) : model.add(BatchNormalization())
    if (dropout[4] > 0) : model.add(Dropout(dropout[4]))

model.add(Dense(OutputCount, activation='linear'))

model.summary()
```

Comment: Is it possible to put some part of your code that you think is relevant? You start your network with Dropout which is really strange.

Comment: The original text by Srivastava indicates dropout in the input layer.  I tried to copy that concept.  I've added some code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Dropout is good as a regularization technique. But the value of the dropout is kind of a hyperparameter and you have to tune it.

What dropout does is basically shutting down a specified percentage of neurons so that the network can see what neurons that are not shut down are picking up - if it's a useless information or not. Every time a different set of neurons is shut down, at random.

So, I think that the problem for you is a too high percentage of shut down neurons (50%). Tune it down to 20%-30%. Another mistake is using dropout before the last layer as well as the first layer. Remove those 2 dropout layers and tune down the percentage of the dropout (dropout rate) and you should be fine :)